# is possible to transfer money from user paypal to bank account of someone who not have paypal?

Tags: paypal, online-payment, payment

is possible to transfer money from user paypal to bank account of someone who not have paypal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not possible. PayPal only supports:

- transfers between two PayPal accounts, and
- transfers between a PayPal account and its *associated* bank accounts or cards.

This makes PayPal unsuitable as a general payment method or as a general-purpose bank account.

To transfer money to a recipient who doesn't want to open a PayPal account, you will need to use a different method. If the money you want to send is on the PayPal account, you will first have to withdraw it to your own bank account.

I too would *love* being able to transfer money without having to withdraw it first, because a direct transfer would circumvent PayPal's exorbitant currency conversion fees.